# Function add of Vector doesn't work

Tags: java, vector

I have a class of `Line` and a fit constructor.

I defined:

```
Line l1 = new Line("A", "B");
```

I have a class `ts`, that has a member: `Vector<Line> allLines = new Vector<Line>();`

I want to add the line `l1` into this vector..

I tried three options but it doesn't work:

```
ts.allLines.addElement(l1);
```

but I got the error:

> `The method addElement(Line) in the type Vector<Line> is not
>   applicable for the arguments (Line)`

```
ts.allLines.add(l1);
```

but I got:

> `The method add(Line) in the type Vector<Line> is not applicable for
>   the arguments (Line)`

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why use a `Vector` in 2013?

Comment: you need to show us the smallest possible program.

Comment: Your code looks ok - the problem is in the code you have not shown yet.

Comment: Please show a small, *complete* example which recreates the error.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your import for Line class are correct. You may have imported a wrong Line class.

Comment: thank you. my line class is found in: HW11/src/Line.java. so I have to import: HW11.src.Line?

Answer (score 2):

Your class should look like this:

```
package com.example;  
import java.util.Vector;  
import com.example.Line;

public class Foo  
{  
    Vector<Line> lines = new Vector<Line>();  

    public void add(Line line)  
    {
         this.lines.add(line);
    }  
}
```

make sure you are importing both the correct `Vector` class and the correct `Line` class.

Comment: thank you. my line class is found in: HW11/src/Line.java.

so I have to import: HW11.src.Line?

Comment: @AlonShmiel most likely yes.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use one of the List implementations, for example ArrayList, instead of Vector. Althrough it is not marked as deprecated, it is in the library only for legacy code support and should be avoided. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated) highlights several problems with the Vector class.